# releasing a non-ios 6 app, today. allowed?

Tags: ios, ios6

I've got an app that's about to be submitted, but it was built against iOS 5.1, before iOS 6 was released.

Can this be submitted for release now, or will apple reject it as it's not iOS 6?

Also, as it's 5.1 it uses now-deprecated autorotate/layout methods, which are intended to make it landscape-only.

If an iPhone 5 / iOS 6 user tries to run it, will it actually run in portrait, as it doesn't include the new autorotate methods?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They won't reject it, the app store works by minimum IOS so your project settings should always reflect the earliest IOS your app is compatible with, so if your app is set to 5.1 it will work with IOS 5.1 onwards.

Hope this helps,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

As long as you do not include a larger iPhone 5 launch image, yes.